# How to checkout PHP-5.4.28

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to checkout [branch `PHP-5.4.28`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.4.28) from the official [PHP git repository](https://github.com/php/php-src), but it doesn't work. Here's what happens:

```
git checkout --track origin/PHP-5.4.28
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'PHP-5.4.28' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/PHP-5.4.28' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

So git thinks the branch doesn't exist on github--and if I run `git ls-remote`, the branch is in fact not listed. But if I go to github, the branch is [there](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.4.28).

**Edit:**

This problem was actually caused by two silly mistakes. First I had cloned into a temp area which accidentally had another git repository above it, and second I forgot to `cd` into the clone before trying to checkout the branch. So git was looking in the outer repository, not in PHP at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new branch for this to work:

```
git checkout -b PHP-5.4.28 --track origin/PHP-5.4.28
```

As an alternative shortcut, you can also do this when the local branch does not exist yet:

```
git checkout PHP-5.4.28
```